# ActionMode not supported in Support Library v21 on ICS?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm developing an app where I use `ActionMode`.

Project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0+'
}
```

API levels:

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
```

My fragment uses `ActionMode`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.packing_list_context, menu);
    return true;
}
...
```

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/context_menu_item_edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/context_menu_item_edit" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/context_menu_item_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/context_menu_item_delete" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/context_menu_item_tags"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_label_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/context_menu_item_tags" />
</menu>
```

When I run this app on Android 4.4, everything is fine. But when I run it on Android 4.0.3, I receive the following exception somewhere at Support Library:

Stack trace:

```
W/System.err( 7292): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:634)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapperICS.getSupportActionProvider(MenuItemWrapperICS.java:322)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapperICS.checkActionProviderOverrideVisibility(MenuItemWrapperICS.java:348)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapperICS.setVisible(MenuItemWrapperICS.java:183)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:425)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:479)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
W/System.err( 7292): at net.cornplay.tourist.fragments.PackingListFragment.onCreateActionMode(PackingListFragment.java:392)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onCreateActionMode(AbsListView.java:5635)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:151)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1367)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.dispatchOnCreate(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1012)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.startActionMode(WindowDecorActionBar.java:510)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.startSupportActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:576)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.startActionModeForChild(ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.java:62)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout.startActionModeForChild(NativeActionModeAwareLayout.java:44)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:3607)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.widget.AbsListView.setItemChecked(AbsListView.java:952)
W/System.err( 7292): at net.cornplay.tourist.fragments.PackingListFragment.onItemLongClick(PackingListFragment.java:350)
W/System.err( 7292): at net.cornplay.tourist.adapters.PackingListAdapter$2.onLongClick(PackingListAdapter.java:87)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:3547)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:14088)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 7292): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
W/System.err( 7292): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7292): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 7292): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
W/System.err( 7292): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
W/System.err( 7292): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Google hints to these issues: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77724, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78212. But how can they be related to my code? I don't use `ShareActionProvider`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the similar issue on Android L Preview tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1660.

Comment: Hey I got a very similar crash report of my app. Did you solve this issue? Can you try it on your 4.0.x device, to verify it's the same issue? Here's my app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager . In order to activate the action mode, either long click an item or single click an icon. Thing is, I don't use getActionProvider or even a ShareActionProvider. I just use "startSupportActionMode" ...

Comment: @androiddeveloper I checked your app on 4.0.3 - it doesn't crash.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is a bug in AppCompat library. It's fixed in v21.0.2. Just upgraded and app doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: hi where can i find new appcompat version, i have update android sdk and use new one but i can't solve that bug